# RPI 3B+ Sound Issues

Tags: audio

I have RPI3 B+ with raspbian and retro pi. The sole purpose is to play retro games. While playing Castlevania SOTN I can hear sound effects but not the in game music. This is the only game I have played so far with this issue. I figured it some obscure setting imbedded somewhere but have not located it and would need some detailed help. It’s that or the person who provided the SD card to me never had the music loaded on it.

So how can I get the in game music working?

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: So how can I get the in game music working?

Comment: If you can hear *anything* from the game, the hardware is working.  It's likely that the music and sound effects are two different "tracks." Perhaps RetroPie isn't playing the music track.  Another possibility, the music is copyrighted and not included in the copy you have of the game.  Or, as you say, perhaps the music was never loaded.  We don't have enough information to answer your question.

Comment: So that leaves us with the possible fixable possibility of retro pi not playing the music track as if it is copyrighted or not downloaded I’m out of luck. Does anyone know how to access/modify the music files in retro pi to enable the soundtracks should they even be there?

Comment: This is not an answer. You should not use answers to ask. Instead edit your question and put additional questions there. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 2):

Background music in games is typically mp3/ogg/aac/etc track, sound effects are mostly use wav format or similar. As for me it seems that some codecs are missed, for example music could use wma or some other format that is not installed by default. You can try to install FFmpeg, or VLC which contain many audio/video codecs.